# I can't see my products images when magento is in english

Tags: php, magento

I am trying to make my magento shop in English too, everything is good but when i make the shop in English i can't see the images from products. My site is in German, in manage products i select a product and i can see the images in the German site and in the English site too, but in the German site the images are marked in store view normally, but when i make the site in English i can see the images but i have the check box no image marked, I can change that but i have to do that to each product and i have more than 700 products.

There is a way to do it fast? example in every product is the same check box marked.

Comment: In language folder check images for `en` exist or not.

Comment: check if the product is assigned to the newly created website/store view in magento.